# Find irreducible components of $V(y − x^2, y^2 − y + z^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field. Find irreducible components of $X=V(y − x^2, y^2 − y + z^2)$ in $F^3$.

I think the variety itself is irreducible, but I couldn't prove that. I normally use the following approaches to check whether the variety is irreducible.

1. If I had $x - y^2$ as a generator instead of $y-x^2$ then the variety is a graph of a polynomial map (e.g $f: X \rightarrow F, X=V(y^2-y+z^2)$ which is irreducible).
2. parameterization
3. high school algebra (solving for $y − x^2=0$ and $y^2 − y + z^2=0$)
4. Show that $I(X)$ prime or $A(X)$ is isomorphic to an integral domain.

Comment: Hint: you can rewrite all occurances of $y$ in terms $x$ using the relation $y-x^2=0$. Do you see how this makes things simpler? (This corresponds to an isomorphism $F[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,y^2-y+z^2)\to F[x,z]/I$ where you have to fill in some details about what $I$ is.)